# View state variable not accessed via javascript

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I don't understand why I am not able to use my view state variable in the java script. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you are trying to achieve, please? Right now, it's almost impossible to answer your question. Viewstate is encrypted and compressed to prevent it from being modified on the client

Answer (score 4):

The viewstate is not designed for used by the javascript. The viewstate is used to remember the values that you have set on code behind and used again on post back.

If you wish to get any value of control you can do that with simple javascript, there is not reason to use the viewstate.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the viewstate directly but simply access the hidden form element that holds the viewstate. I would suggests to use RegisterHiddenField than mixing server/js codes:

You may try this sample:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ViewState("code") = "EE"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("vCode", ViewState("code"))
End Sub
```

On your javascript:

> var vCode = document.getElementById("vCode");
>   alert(vCode);

Answer (score 1):

The viewstate is encrypted. You're not supposed to be able to read it.

If you want to access parameters of a control, expose it via a property.

```
public string Label1Text
{
    get
    {
        return Label1.Text;
    }
}

<script>
    var lblText = "<%= this.Label1Text %>";
</script>
```